# Perl module for text comparison

Tags: perl, cpan

Can anyone suggest a Perl module which can compare two strings and return a degree to which they match? I searched CPAN extensively, and although there are similar modules like **String::Approx** and **Data::Compare**, they are not what I am looking for. Suppose I have two strings : **I love you**, and **I boht you**. I want functionality which will compare these two strings, taking into account numerous parameters, the matching of words in correct order (**love** as the first word in a string should not "match" **love** as the 4th word in the 2nd string, even though both strings have that word), words not matching but spelt almost similarly (like say **love** and **loge**), number of words, etc and return an index, say a number from 0 to 1 on a scale of 1, representing the degree of similarity between the two strings. Is there any such Perl module?

Comment: Would http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Levenshtein/Levenshtein.pm do what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, I am not sure, the examples and Wikipedia article on Levenshtein distance deal in word comparisons only, no string comparison. So I don't know how will it compare strings with some of the words matching but in different positions, which should not amount to a match.

Comment: Doing that sort of string comparison is something that humans do trivially, but which are really hard to do with a computer.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's very ambitious! But Perl does so many wonderful things, so may be something like this has been designed already!

Comment: You haven't said anything that excludes `Text::Levenshtein`. It sounds like you have only a vague idea how you want the strings compared. The Levenshtein distance is the number of character insertions, deleteions or changes necessary to convert one string to another. `I love you` vs. `I boht you` would score 3, and vs. `I loge you` would score 1. What do you want different from that?

Comment: Yeah, perhaps that will do, I am not sure, and you are right, I have just a vague idea about exactly what kind of comparison I am gonna do. Will try it and let you know! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many such modules. Often, though, you'll have to make use of them in some special way to account for your own assumptions. Most of the string comparison tools like this just implement some algorithm for comparing one string to another. Most assume that if you have specific policy decisions to make, you'll code them yourself.

Personally, I am not sure I'd recommend [Text::Levenshtein](http://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aLevenshtein) because of bugs and lack of ut8 support. I don't have a better recommendation either, though.

However, these searches will reveal lots of potential modules you could look into and determine what works best for your purpose (based on the names of common algorithms for doing this sort of thing):

- https://metacpan.org/search?q=levenshtein
- https://metacpan.org/search?q=wagner+fischer
- https://metacpan.org/search?q=edit+distance

If you're interested in spoken similarities, you can also look into phonetic comparisons:

- https://metacpan.org/search?q=phonetic
- https://metacpan.org/search?q=soundex
- https://metacpan.org/search?q=metaphone

Comment: Wow. Lots of resources, will be looking them all up. Thanks!