# How can I find the percentage of a regex match on a string?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm involved in a digital radio propagation study where a remote transmitter sends a predefined beacon at a defined time that's easily matched with a regex.

But due to solar and atmospheric conditions it's not always a 100% decoded. What I want to do is calculate the percentage of the decode.

The beacon format is as so:

```
de va6shs va6shs va6shs Loc DO46gs Olivia-4-250 NBEMS test 2218Z 
     |                        |          |                   |
 (Station)               (Location) (Digital Mode)       (UTC Time)
```

Can I actually figure out the percentage with Perl, or should I be looking for another solution?

Edit: What often happens as there is limited error correction in the data mode we are using so random characters often end up in the decoded string or characters are not decode at all these are received strings from the same station at different times of the same day as solar conditions degraded.

```
100% decode 
de ve6rfm ve6rfm ve6rfm Loc DO46gs Olivia-4-250 NBEMS test 0218Z

93.75% 
P!de ve6rfm ve6rfm ve6rfm Loc DO46gs Olivia-4-250 NBEMS <TAB>est F248Z

9.375% 
de ve6rfmr&
```

The only difference there should be between the two beacon strings is the UTC time at the end of the string, but as you can see there's a few characters that didn't decode correctly.

The correctly decodes string has 64 characters.
The first incorrectly decoded string has 60 correct characters.
So 60/64 * 100 = 93.75% decode.

My regex for the station call sign, the three repeated words is

```
 /[vV][aAeEyY][15678]\w{2,3}/
```

There are several different stations involved in the study across western Canada so I need to capture them as propagation permits, and using the above regex saves me from having to update my script every time a new station comes on the air.

Comment: with what you've shown, what would be your expected output, and which column is the number that decides the %?

Comment: 1) Match the things that would be 100% 2) Calculate the [Leveshtein Dinstance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and do some arithmetic.

Comment: Do you mean that you do get some match and want to see what part of the whole string that match is?

Comment: You'll need to make parts of the pattern optional. Then you can get the length of the match and compare it to the length of a full beacon, and you'll know how much of it you received.

Comment: I need to test the entire string to determine the decode rate.

Comment: @SeanSmith  Thank you for the update.  (1) So this "beacon" that you show, that is the whole string to be parsed, correct? (2) What is the ultimate, exact goal -- To know that the beacon _is_ there and its percent match to the expected?  To actually read off things that you marked, all or just some?

Comment: @zdim The goal is to determine the percentage match so we can compare against solar data and say when these solar conditions exist there is a confidence level of x that the two stations will be able to reliably communicate. The solar conditions side we've got locked down it's the beacon side that's giving us issues now. Another way to look at it how confident are we that the decoded data is correct.

Comment: @SeanSmith  I rewrote and restored my answer, reviewing three modules that give you directly related measures. Some can probably be used to get exactly what you want with some more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is one of partial or fuzzy matching. There are modules out there that may help.  They mostly use *Levenshtein distance*, the number of edits needed to get one string from the other, but there are other methods. See a partial list in [Text::Levenshtein](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Levenshtein/lib/Text/Levenshtein.pm). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763875/perl-module-for-text-comparison) for search phrases that will offer far more.

Here are examples using [String::Approx](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-Approx/Approx.pm), [String::Similarity](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/String-Similarity-1.04/Similarity.pm), and [Text::Fuzzy](http://search.cpan.org/~bkb/Text-Fuzzy-0.24/lib/Text/Fuzzy.pod). None gives exactly what you ask but all retrieve similar measures, and have options that may allow you to get your target.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

my $beacon = 
    'de va6shs va6shs va6shs Loc DO46gs Olivia-4-250 NBEMS test 2218Z';
my $received = 
    'P!de ve6rfm ve6rfm ve6rfm Loc DO46gs Olivia-4-250 NBEMS <TAB>est F248Z';

# Can use an object, or the functional interface
use Text::Fuzzy qw(fuzzy_index distance_edits);
my $tf = Text::Fuzzy->new ($beacon);   

my ($offset, $edits, $distance);
# Different distance/edits
$distance = $tf->distance($received);
($offset, $edits, $distance) = fuzzy_index    ($received, $beacon);
($distance, $edits)          = distance_edits ($received, $beacon);

# Provides "similarity", in terms of edit distance
use String::Similarity;  
my $similarity = similarity $beacon, $received;

# Can be tuned, but is more like regex in some sense. See docs.
use String::Approx qw(amatch);
my @matches = amatch($beacon, $received);  # within 10% 
# amatch($beacon, ["20%"], $received);     # within 20%
# amatch($beacon, ["S0"], $received);      # no "substitutions"
```

Please look through their documentation.

The `String::Approx` considers a "match" if it is not further than 10% in length.  This is the default, and the module allows to adjust that parameter. For example,

```
amatch($beacon, ["20%"], $received);
```

would make that 20%. Other refinements of possible use for you can be made. 
 Newer versions of the module are written in C and are much better perfoming.

Comment: I think he's saying that the string doesn't always match the entire pattern, because part of the string is missing.

Comment: @Barmar  So that they don't know what to match in fact?  That's different, sure.  Thank you.  I'll wait for a clarification ...

Comment: Thanks @zdim, I will try these out over the weekend. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back the the question String::Similarity is working great for my project.

Comment: @SeanSmith  Well, that's great to hear -- and useful to know!

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the number of characters matching compared to the length of the initial string, for instance looking for `/\bva\dshs\b/` (`\b` is a *word boundary*, and `\d` is a *digit*, see [the manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#The-backslash))

```
my $s = 'de va6shs va6shs va6shs Loc DO46gs Olivia-4-250 NBEMS test 2218Z';

my $r = join('', $s =~ m/\bva\dshs\b/g);

print(((length($r)*100) / length($s)) . "%\n");
```

The matching strings, combined, give

```
"va6shsva6shsva6shs"
```

which is **28.125%** of the initial string length.

Comment: I think he's saying that he doesn't always get a match for the whole pattern. He wants to know how much of the pattern was matched.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks. not time to improve this ;-)

Comment: That's correct I don't always get a match in the full pattern, I'm trying to figure out what percentage of the pattern does match.