# Matching consecutive characters from a string using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm not sure how to title this question, so moving along...

I'd like to be able to match a portion of a string that is a subset of a larger string. For example:

- MatchPartOfThisString -> Reference string
- fThisDiff -> string I'd like to be able to say matches 5 consecutive characters in

I suppose I could loop through the first string, taking the minimum number of consecutive matches from the reference string, and see if the other string matches each of the matches I get from systematically trying to match:

```
if(fThisDiff =~ /Match/) {
    do something...;
}
if(fThisDiff =~ /atchP/) {
    do something...;
}
if(fThisDiff =~ /tchPa/) {
    do something...;
}
```

etc.

I'd like to do this more elegantly though, if there is a way to interpret portions of the reference string repeatedly with a singular regex. I do not think this is the case, but I'd like confirmation regardless.

Comment: look into "fuzzy matching."  see for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010321/4653379) for a list of some modules with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic take on it, by hand with builtin tools.

Build a regex pattern with alternation of substrings of desired length from your reference string.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

sub get_alt_re {
    my ($str, $len) = @_; 
    $len //= 1;            #/
    my @substrings;
    foreach my $beg (0 .. length($str)-$len) {
        push @substrings, substr($str, $beg, $len);
    }
    return '(' .  join('|', map quotemeta, @substrings) . ')';
}   

my $ref    = q(MatchPartOfThisString);
my $target = q(fThisDiff);

my $re = get_alt_re($ref, 5);

my @m = $target =~ /$re/g;
say for @m;
```

Prints the line `fThis`.

The code should be made more robust and general. Then, it is fairly easily modified to match for a range of lengths (not only one, 5 above). Further, it can use libraries for subtasks (those repeated calls to `substr` beg for C code).  But this demonstrates that a basic solution can be rather simple.

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple way to do this with regex features, but a couple CPAN modules can help construct such a regex in this case.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use String::Substrings 'substrings';
use Data::Munge 'list2re';

my $match_string = 'MatchPartOfThisString';
my $re = list2re substrings $match_string, 5;
my $subject = 'fThisDiff';
if ($subject =~ m/($re)/) {
  print "Matched $1 from $match_string in $subject\n";
}
```

Comment: @WetCheerios Both functions are very simple and pure-perl so you could copy them from the source (you can find this on metacpan), as long as you maintain the licensing/copyright. Alternatively you can install modules [locally](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib), [bundle](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) them with your project, or [fatpack](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) them into a script if any of those would be allowed.

Comment: @WetCherious Why are you can not add modules? Define environment **PERL5LIB** and  use cpan to install modules -- the modules will be installed where you point **PERL5LIB** variable.

Comment: @WetCheerios, If you can add a script, you can add a module. There's no difference.

Comment: @PolarBear Modules are not installed using PERL5LIB, that only adds locations to load them from. Two easy ways to define where to install to are by activating a local::lib (which also sets up PERL5LIB), or using `cpanm -l /path/to/local`.

Comment: @Grinnz For many years I was using `perl -MCPAN -e shell` or `perl -MCPAN -e install Some::Module` and it never failed me at least in Linux. When **PERL5LIB** variable was set, the module installation proceed successfully into designated filesystem location (location should allow to write files).

Comment: @PolarBear CPAN can be configured to install somewhere else. PERL5LIB is not how to do it. Dunno what to tell you.

Comment: @Grinnz Ok, how would you install some CPAN module on remote Linux server where you very restricted and allowed to write into HOME directory only. Let's say what would be procedure to install **Some::Module** into **~/.perl** directory?

Comment: @PolarBear `PERL5LIB` doesn't tell where to install. You must have had `cpan` configured our `PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT` configured to tell Makefile.PL/Build.PL to install elsewhere.

Comment: @PolarBear I mentioned two options. `cpanm -l ~/.perl Some::Module` or having a local::lib activated in your environment pointing to that directory.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to use the [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) algorithm (not to be confused with the similarly-named [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm) then check its length.

```
use String::LCSS_XS qw( lcss );

my $longest = lcss("MatchPartOfThisString", "fThisDiff");
say length($longest);
```

If you have really long strings and you want to to squeeze out every millisecond, a tailored version of the algorithm that quits as soon as the target length is found and that avoids building the string would be faster.